# How to configure Charles to capture traffic from stand alone flash player?

Tags: php, flash, amf, charles-proxy

I got a .swf that sends and receive some data from a server (AMFPHP), localhost in my case, but Charles doesn't seem to be able to capture the traffic. I've tested it on Chrome and with other apps and it works ok, it's just the Flash player standalone that doesn't seem to be very friendly with Charles :P

Answer (score 0):

have you looked in Charles Menu-> Proxy? There's a setting for having a proxy for the system and another for the os. The os one should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

ServiceCapture should be able to do this for you and decode the AMF.

http://kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/